# Is there a way to add a cell value to a running total based on a neighboring cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a workbook to replace a company step challenge that is no longer available to us. The goal is to track steps in as real-time as possible (users will select their name from a drop-down in Cell E2 and input their steps into Cell F2). The drop-down is based on Column A using Data Validation and in Column B is their running total of steps. I would like to have a Control Button in place in Column G that takes the number of step inputted by the user and adds to the current steps for that same user in Column B.

So far, I have Data Validation running fine without issue and I have mock users in Column A and their steps in Column B. I assume the logic behind the coding would need to be Selecting the value in Cell E2 and locating that value in Column A. Once the code has a value of true, move over 1 cell to the right, add value in Cell F2 to that current selected cell value, and then delete value from Cell F2.

I attempted to start off with a range.find and I'm under the impression that is incorrect because I keep receiving errors. I then took to already posted questions to find someone with a similar issue but spent an hour just trying to create a patchwork code that didn't work in the end.

Any and all suggestions or links to forums/posts I wasn't able to locate myself would be greatly appreciated. I'm going to continue to search but as a newbie, some items I am finding are well above my skill/comprehension level.

EDIT:

So I've changed my approach based on comments. I now have a list of names spread over columns J2:S2 (this will grow as people sign-up). What I'm now attempting to do is write code that will find the person's name in the column based on cell value E2, then paste the steps they have inputted into cell F2 to the next blank row of that column. I put together another attempt at code but there is something wrong that I cannot figure out (See below). I will then just make a pivot based off of the data that will sit off the the left in Columns A:C.

With the below code I do not get any errors, nothing happens other than the clear contents. Sorry for the time before replying to comments, I wanted to attempt to do this on my own before coming back with an edit. I think there is something going on with me not specifying a cell value more clearly or I am misusing the rng.value as a way to paste rather than just check for a value.

I'm a greenhorn for sure with VBA so I'm learning rules as I go.

```
Sub Attempt_3()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2:S2").End(xlDown)
For Each Row In rng
    If rng.Value = "E2" Then
        rng.Value = rng.Offset(1, 0).Value = "F2"
    End If
Next Row

Range("F2").Select
Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the code you've tried so far, and a description of the error(s) that occur?

Comment: From a data architecture point of view, taking an input and adding it to an existing value, then clearing the input, is a very bad idea. The user will have no clue which numbers contributed to the current total for a specific person and you can't tell if an entry has accidentally been duplicated, or a wrong number entered. A much more robust data architecture would be to add each new entry at the bottom of a raw data table, then build a report with formulas or a pivot table that summarizes the data per users. That is what Excel was made for.